# T4 generator problem

Tags: t4, visual-studio-2010

I just switched to the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Release Candidate, from Beta 2, and [the T4 generator that I've been using](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) doesn't work anymore. When I run it, I get an error message that says:

> "Failed to resolve include text for
>   file:The path '\L2ST4.ttinclude'
>   must be either local to this computer
>   or part of your trusted zone."

I'd had this before, and it disappeared on its own, but now it's back with a vengeance. I've tried removing the generator and adding it again, but the error persists.

The include file is in the same directory as the .tt file that is doing my generation, so I'm not sure why it can't find it. This is the line of code referring to the file it can't find:

```
<#@ include file="L2ST4.ttinclude"#>
```

I have a [post](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=81038) up at the generator's codeplex site, but I don't think this is an issue specific to this generator, I think it's a T4/Visual Studio thing in general, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. Plus, the SO community is the one of the fastest ways to get an answer, and this issue is really holding me back.

Comment: At the risk of seeming obvious, is the path `'\L2ST4.ttinclude'` either local to your computer, or part of your trusted zone?

Comment: It's a file in the same directory as the template, so yeah it's local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creator of the generator replied to my post. It's a file protection thing. The work-around was to create new files of the same name and copying in the text from the old files. Since these files were created on my local computer, there was no conflict.

Comment: +1 Thanks for asking and answering this question. It was helpful to me.

Comment: The trick didn't work for me, but I managed to compile by simply copy/pasting the contents of the file to be included. Suboptimal, but compiles